# Is there a way to proportionally shrink or enlarge a whole css file?

Tags: html, css, resize

This may be obvious to you, but I'm definitely clueless.  I basically have a bunch of css that works fine, but appears way to large.  I want to cut it into a quarter without going into it and changing each and every value.  For instance I'd like many things like this:

```
#p1
    {
        width: 1285px;
        height: 1388px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

to change into something like this:

```
#p1
    {
        width: 321px;
        height: 347px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

I just want to retain the functionality but shrink it to fit better on the page.  Please tell me there's a way to do this outside of using a calculator and a whole lot of patience.

Comment: Have you had a look into jQuery and the JavaScript plugin?

Comment: It would be possible to change the sizes proportional by changing one or two values, when the CSS is build with proportional measurements (%, em). But your CSS file uses pixel. That means you have to change every single value. Seems you have to use calculator and patience.

Comment: Or like Sam says using javascript to divide width and height of all elements by 4. But that is not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Or write a script that performs a regex on the numbers, divides them by x, and updates them?